# Zend Framework 2: Save session on every page load – front controller plugin?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2, I want to create a module that saves something into a session on every page load (no views involved, no database involved). The saved data needs to be accessible application-wide.

At first I thought a controller plugin would be the way to go, but then I realized that a plugin will do nothing until used in a controller. Since I don't want to alter every controller to call the plugin, I don't think this is an option anymore.

While doing some research, I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032949/correct-way-to-deal-with-application-wide-data-needed-on-every-pageview), where a "front controller plugin" is suggested. While this looks like a solution that could work for me, I am not sure how to implement it in ZF2?

Of course I could do everything in the `onBootstrap` function, but I don't think it's the right place to do such things, but where how should I approach the task, where is the correct place for code that runs on every page load in ZF2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedEventManager in init() method of Module.php class.

You can register listener to MVC dispatch event and run your code on dispatch event triggered by Zend Framework 2.

For example:

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
{
    $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach('*', 'dispatch', function($e){
            //do your work
    });
}
```

Important! This code just register callback for dispatch event, thats means code placed in callback function do our work in controller dispatch time, not module init time.

Comment: I upvoted for solution, But I think we need not to use sharedmanager. only event manager also do the trick.  `$moduleManager->getEventManager()->attach('dispatch', function($e){    //do your work });`

Comment: What version of ZF2 you are using? I cannot do that trick on 2.3.3 without sharedmanager. Now i think my solution is not better because dispatch event in ZF2 triggering two time. MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE is many useful instead dispatch event